# Typescript error in devextreme-react Datagrid - ts(2559)

Tags: typescript, devexpress, devextreme

Our devextreme-react datagrid has suddenly stopped working. We get an error :
`Type '{ children: Element[]; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<DataGrid<any, any>> & Readonly<IDataGridOptions<any, any>>'.ts(2559)`
on the  component.

Anyone seen this error before? It was working, but stopped working. Devextreme webpage has no good information about solutions.

We are using versions:

```
    "devextreme": "21.2.4",
    "devextreme-react": "21.2.4",
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Migrating from 20.2.5 to 21.2.7 with React and Typescript from 16.12.0 to 18.0.0 and Typescript from 3.9.5 to 4.6.3. Devextreme should solve this issue, I have tried almost everything. I have node v16.13.1 and npm 8.1.2

Comment: I'm facing the exact same issue.
This is a thread already talking about this. Unfortunately, there's still no solution.
https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t1083829/widgets-are-not-working-with-types-react-v18

Answer (score 0):

It should be working now. You need to update to the version 21.2.8 and it will work again.